# How to write RSpec to check if associated record exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, associations

I am beginner to RSpec. I am having a model `teacher` that `has_many :lessons`. Here is my FactoryGirls records:

spec/factories/lessons.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :lesson do
    title "Rspec test"
    description "test description"
    company_name "narola pvt"
    association :teacher
    location "Zwanenplein 34"
    days_to_pay 2
  end
end
```

spec/factories/teachers.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :teacher do
    first_name "Teacher's name"
    last_name "Teacher's last name"
    address "los angeles"
    city "california"
    zip_code "12345"
    country "USA"
    birthdate nil
    phone nil
    password "password"
    email { "example#{SecureRandom.uuid}@email.dummy" }
  end
end
```

Following is my try with models test:

spec/models/teacher_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Teacher, type: :model do
  let(:teacher) { FactoryGirl.create(:teacher) }

  it "should have at least one lesson" do
    config.expect_with(Lesson.where(teacher_id: teacher)){|c| c.syntax = :should}
  end
end
```

I am willing to write a rspec test case to find if lesson exists for particular lesson.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
it "should have at least one lesson" do
   expect(Lesson.where(teacher_id: teacher.id)).to exist    
end
```

Let me know if it's work for you. I haven't try this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. It worked for me. And i also tried it following way, and it worked. :)
`expect(teacher.lessons).to be_present`

Answer (score 0):

`it "should have at least one lesson" do
   expect(Lesson.where(teacher_id: teacher.id).exists?).to be_truthy
end`

This would be faster because of the use of 'exists?' method compared to
`expect(Lesson.where(teacher_id: teacher.id)).to exist`

Underlying query execution due to use of 'exists?' the method is fast. More details are here -> 
https://www.ombulabs.com/blog/benchmark/performance/rails/present-vs-any-vs-exists.html